# Using substring to extract part of a string

Tags: kotlin

I have the following string:
`https://dummycloud/image/fetch/f_webp,q_auto:best,w_1080,c_limit/auto/https://dummy.com/media/products/8/8/763160.jpg`

And I am only interested in the this part that comes at the end: `https://dummy.com/media/products/8/8/763160.jpg`

I am using the following with StringBuilder

```
val url = imageUrl.substringAfterLast("https")

return StringBuilder()
    .append("https")
    .append(url)
    .toString()
```

Just wondering if there is a substringAfterLast that would keep the prefix `https`. As I have to use StringBuilder manually to append it from the extract string.

Comment: Btw why are you using a StringBuilder instead of just `"https$url"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf(“https”));
```